# C++: Efficiently extracting a subset of elements from a datatype that only has access via an iterator

Tags: c++, vector, sample, subset

I have another persons user defined data structure (for working on meshes). The only public access to the underlying elements is via an iterator (no direct access to "element" x is possible).

I also have a list of element indices, stored as a std::vector which I want to extract, where I will define the first element visited by the iterator as index=1, index=2, etc. Effectively I am wanting to extract a subset of the elements based on index.

I will be doing this a large number of times (the mesh from which I am sampling will be ever changing and I want to keep sampling the same indices), thus I need as an efficient method as possible.

At the moment, I really can't think of a more efficient way than adding all elements to a std::vector, then looping through the element index list and selecting all the required elements. Ideally for both time and storage reasons this doesn't seem a very neat way of doing it.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you access the elements via an offset to the start iterator, i.e. `*(data.begin() + offset)`?

Comment: Instead of adding all of the elements to the list, use a counter in your iterator loop, adding elements only when your counter = your next index. That way you can do it with one pass and without having to copy out of an intermediate vector. You will also need to keep track of which index you are on and have the indices in sorted order

Comment: @arc If the data structure were static, that would work, but the question indicates that the data structure contents will be dynamically changing.  Any intermediate data structure used, `std::vector<>` or otherwise, would have to be rebuilt every time the data structure changes...

Comment: @hatboyzero, regardless you must look at each element in the data structure succession each time you need to take a sample. Both my method and oracles are doing that, but oracles is using a temporary vector to store ALL of the elements even though he doesnt need them

Comment: @arc Fair enough, but I think oracle3001 is attempting to avoid the reevaluation step if I understand the question correctly...

Answer (score 2):

If the vector is sorted beforehand then you would only need to iterate once. You will need to maintain the count in the 3rd-party iterator yourself though. Try a variant of the code below. *(Note: This code is missing error and bounds checking.)*

```
iterator elementIt;
int elementPos = 0;

vector<int> extractElements;
for (vector<int>::iterator extractIt = extractElements.begin(); extractIt != extractElements.end(); ++extractIt)
{
  while (elementPos < *extractIt)
  {
    ++elementIt;
    ++elementPos;
  }

  doSomething(elementIt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can access the exposed `iterator` object via an offset from an existing `iterator` object (i.e. via a `begin()` getter method), you might be able to do the following

```
DataStructure_type::iterator iter = dataStructureVar.begin();
elementValue = *(iter + idx);
```

Where `DataStructure_type` is the type of the iterable data structure, and `idx` is the index of the element you are wanting.  Then, extracting a subset of the elements from the data structure becomes as simple as:

```
DataStructure_type::iterator subsetStartIter = dataStructureVar.begin() + subsetStartIdx;
DataStructure_type::iterator subsetEndIter = dataStructureVar.begin() + subsetEndIdx;
std::vector<Element_type> subsetCollection(subsetStartIter, subsetEndIter);
```

But it might be more efficient if you operated directly on the original subset `iterator` objects in your code rather than copying them to an intermediate container -- this would eliminate the need for copying the subset to a `std::vector<>`...

Do note that this answer is making certain assumptions about the implementation of the exposed `iterator` object in `DataStructure_type` and doesn't account for boundary checking.